# Redirect root domain to subdomain

Tags: linux, nginx

I am trying to redirect:

```
pt.example.com and example.com
```

to

```
https://pt.example.com
```

- `pt.example.com` will redirect to `https://pt.example.com`. That's ok.
- `example.com` will redirect to `https://example.com` (not `https://pt.example.com` as expected)

---

```
 server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
            server_name pt.example.com;
            return 301 https://pt.example.com$request_uri;
    }
```

How can I correct that?

Comment: HSTS on `example.com` will make the browser automatically switch from `http` to `https` - Nginx is not involved. What you need is an `https://example.com` to `https://pt.example.com` redirect.

Comment: @RichardSmith probably the redirect without the subdomain is due the HSTS.

Comment: Right, you have to redirect twice, one from http to https, and then from domain to subdomain. Otherwise HSTS doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

So that HSTS works properly, you need to redirect from http to https on the same hostname, and then redirect on https from the first hostname to the second hostname.

This also means that both hostnames must have a TLS certificate. Ideally they should be alternate names on the same certificate, to simplify maintenance.

Here is a live working example pulled from one of my production sites:

```
server {
        server_name www.yes-www.org yes-www.org;

        include includes/listen-80;
        include includes/cloudflare;
        include includes/letsencrypt;

        access_log off;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Above, we simply redirect from http to https on the same hostname, whatever it was.

```
server {
        server_name yes-www.org;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.yes-www.org/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.yes-www.org/privkey.pem;

        include includes/listen-443;
        include includes/cloudflare;
        include includes/ssl;
        include includes/ssl_stapling;
        include includes/hsts;
        include includes/letsencrypt;

        return 301 https://www.yes-www.org$request_uri;
}
```

Here we redirect from one hostname to the other on https. The destination hostname is in the `return` directive.

If you have additional hostnames to redirect from one hostname to the destination hostname, they can all be served from the same `server` block as long as they all share the same TLS certificate. Otherwise, duplicate the `server` block.

```
server {
        server_name www.yes-www.org;

        root /srv/www/yes-www.org;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/yes-www.org-access.log nginx;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/cache.log cache;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/yes-www.org-error.log;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.yes-www.org/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.yes-www.org/privkey.pem;

        include includes/listen-443;
        include includes/cloudflare;
        include includes/letsencrypt;
        include includes/ssl;
        include includes/ssl_stapling;
        include includes/hsts;

        # more directives to serve the web app itself
        # which you should replace with your own directives
        # to serve your own web app
}
```

And of course, this just serves the web site.

Comment: Sorry but your example seems over-complicated with a lot of non relevant stuff for the question. I just want a minimal working example, already provided the full nginx.conf.

Comment: This already is a minimal working example. You can ignore everything else that isn't relevant for your case, or you can try to learn something from it.

Comment: A minimal working example don't needs to include includes/csp_wordpress; just saying.

Comment: @Fel True, I could make it less real-world, but then it would be less useful. Again, everything you need to know is here, and you can either learn from or ignore the rest. But in any case I've removed some less relevant stuff.

Answer (score 1):

As you already have a default server for your domain, I will assume that this is the only domain hosted at this IP address.

Make one `server` block a default server and give the other `server` block the one true `server_name`. The default server listens on both ports 80 and 443, and does not need a `server_name` statement.

If both domains share the same certificate, you can move the `ssl_certificate` directives above both `server` blocks, as shown in my example.

```
ssl_certificate ...;
ssl_certificate_key ...;

server {
    listen  80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen  443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    return  301 https://pt.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name pt.example.com;

    #
    # this is your main server block for https://pt.example.com
    #
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for more.

Comment: This breaks down if you host many sites, not all of which share the same TLS certificate.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have added a note to my answer regarding my assumptions.

Comment: No success. Same beahaviour. Here is the complete nginx.conf https://textuploader.com/dngtx

Comment: It would be more useful to see the configuration with my answer incorporated, so we can see that it is correct. Also, you will need to restart Nginx without errors and clear the browser cache before the changes take effect.

Comment: I don't have any error with nginx -t, and I can't add the 443 rule for the first server block since it will give an error when loading the website.